# Symfony2 Monolog email only some exceptions

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I am using Monolog in a Symfony2 project and I'm getting tired of seeing exception emails that occur because of Access Denied and a few other cases that are not interesting to me (there are automated requests that cause this).

Is there a way to specify a callback for Monolog that returns true/false depending on whether I want to email it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, you have to override ExceptionListener and take the control over your hands. After this override process, you can send what you want to be emailed.